# Unable to : "Open Terminal here" with byobu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, byobu

In a specific directory, if I right click and select "Open Terminal". It just launches another instance of the terminal in the root location and not the location where I intended it to open.

Is there a workaround for this. I want to be able to Open a terminal in a specific location and attach it as a new split/window in an already running byobu terminal.

For additional info : I added "byobu" to my .bashrc file so that whenever I open a terminal byobu process also starts.
I'm running the default file Manager of Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to also avoid having to type "byobu" in every terminal window, in case anyone else has this problem. Just add the following three lines to your .bashrc:

byobu kill-session -a

byobu new-session -c $PWD

byobu

Or, if you just want to add windows rather than killing and respawning entire sessions, you can instead use:

byobu new-window -c $PWD

byobu

Answer (score 0):

So to simply circumvent the problem, I removed "byobu" from .bashrc. So byoubu wont be enabled by default.

Now when I R-click and open in terminal it should open terminal from that specific directory.
If I want I'll just type "byobu" from there on.

Its a stupid Question and a simple answer.